# Why Copy if newer replaces not only when a file in the output dir is older?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I discovered this issue when I added an Access DB file to my project and set it to Copy if newer:
[image]

I thought it would be copied to the output directory only if a file in the output directory is older than the file in the project directory.

In fact it is copied even if the file in the output directory is newer: for example when I edited and saved it by my program.

Also I tested it in another project using another kind of file (.txt).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) says

> Select Copy if newer if the file is to be copied only when it is newer
>   than an existing file of the same name in the output directory.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand anything. So you change, say in Debug\ folder your file from code, but on next build it reseted with taht one available in your project ?

Comment: Obvious question, you're not rebuilding are you?

Comment: Yes, it is reseted on next rebuild.

Comment: Rebuild is equally to a clean and build, so your files get deleted. Are you really rebuilding or are you just building?

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow Oh, you're right, thank you. I didn't know about clean in rebuild.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turned out you were rebuilding your project. Rebuild is essentially just a clean followed by a build. This means your file got deleted, and as part of the regular build it got copied over (since there is no newer version).

Comment: Maybe you mean "since there is no document at all". Newer version refers to the fact if the version in the project is newer than the existing in the out directory.