# Access Database "Copy Always" when build using C3

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a stupid question, I'm using a windows form app with c#, I have a 2013 access database associated inside the project, the property copy to output directory is "Copy always". When I run the app, the actual db is copied to the bin\Debug folder. Now I perform an insert on a table, everything is fine, but when I go out and run the app again, the insert is gone, because the db is overwritten again in the bin\Debug from the original place.

How can avoid this?

Comment: An Access database is just a file, so if you overwrite the file, you lose any changes. What you're doing is fine in development, and obviously not what you want in production. 
You can move the database file to a separate folder outside of the development environment to avoid overwriting it. What do you want to happen in development?

Comment: I pushed a specific folder for now. No matter I'm debugging or not, it will always refers to the same DB. Thank you

Comment: Change to Copy If new, and then try to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is because you should use "Copy if newer" and don't do a Rebuild: [Why Copy if newer replaces not only when a file in the output dir is older?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940011/why-copy-if-newer-replaces-not-only-when-a-file-in-the-output-dir-is-older)

Also you should probably not put the database file in the output directory. You may put some key in app.config that says where the db is and then access it there.