# OLEDB commands aren't being saved in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

- I'm working in Windows Forms and trying to use OLEDB to connect to an access `.accdb` file.
- I can SELECT data without issue.
- I can execute `Insert` and `Create` commands with no error.
- But when I check the database afterward the data is not showing.

For example, when I create a new Table, the code will say the table was created and if I try to create the table again without closing the Windows Form it will throw an error saying the table already exists, but if I close and restart the program it will let me create the table once more.

Also, if I look into the Access file I wont see the table.
I've tried multiple tests both with Access open and closed.  The Connection String is correct as I have made changes to tables in the Access file and they are reflected in the `SELECT` queries I've sent.

I suspect there must be a setting in Access I must enable for it to autocommit changes.  But I haven't found it.

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =Database2.accdb");
            string query = "INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([Test_Name], [Test_Number]) VALUES (?, ?)";
               try
               {
                   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   cmd.CommandText = query;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Test_Name", list_all_meters[0][0].Name);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Test_Number", list_all_meters[0][0].Value);
                   cmd.Connection = conn;
                   conn.Open();
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 conn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("An Item has been successfully added", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               }catch(Exception ex)
               {
                   Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
               }
```

Comment: Post your code. Are you using transactions? Are you swallowing exceptions?

Comment: _"the code will say the table was created"_ - **how** does the program judge if a table was created or not?

Comment: Share the code which you are using to perform DML transactions. There might be rollback or you might not be commiting.

Comment: @Dai As stated, when I run the same create query again, it will generate an error that states 'Cannot create table as it already exists' or something to that effect.

Comment: I noticed you're passing a short filename to the `Data Source=` connection-string parameter - is it possible that the program is operating on a physically different file, such as a copy in your `bin` dir?

Comment: You should inspect the return-value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`: it returns the number of rows affected by DML, which is far better than how your current code _always_ shows a Success message without ever actually checking for errors...

Comment: Probably you have your database listed between the project files. If you check the property for that item in your project you will see the property Copy To output directory set to Copy Always

Comment: @Dai I have checked to see if the changes were pushed to a different file.  They have not.  I also added a return value for cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().  It shows that 1 row was effected, but once more the Access database doesn't reflect this.

Comment: @DLabadie Run `procmon.exe` and use it to monitor file IO from both your program - and `MSACCESS.EXE` itself. I'm keen to see what it shows.

Comment: @Steve It is indeed set to Copy Always.  Which might be the problem.

Comment: Every time you debug your program the access file in your project folder with old content is being copied into `Bin` folder.

Comment: That did it.  Had to change it to Copy if Newer.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940011/why-copy-if-newer-replaces-not-only-when-a-file-in-the-output-dir-is-older) as well

Comment: @DLabadie consider also that Access, if you open the database file in the project folder, changes the modified date on that file. So even with "copy if newer" you could end having an unexpected copy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was I had set the Database "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy Always, which overwrote my changes every time I ran the program.  Changing it to Copy if Newer fixed the issue.